# JavaScript isn't executing onclick event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have some simple JavaScript functions:

```
function focus(id)
{
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e != null)
    {
        e.focus();
    }
}

function show(id)
{
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e != null)
    {
        e.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

I then have an html `<a>` tag with an `onclick` event:

```
<a title="Click This" onclick="focus('some_textbox'); show('some_panel');">Click This</a>
```

When I click on the "Click This" link, only the `show()` method executes.  From some reason the focus method is never called. Any ideas why this is happening?

I've tried clearing my cache and have reversed the order of the `focus()` and `show()` methods.  I've also verified that everything is spelled correctly.

Is it because `focus()` is already a function within JavaScript?

Edit: I tried renaming the function to focus2 and it seems to work now.  Very strange.  Anybody have any insight into why this happens?

Comment: If `show` is executed, `focus` is as well, maybe you cannot see the effect, maybe it is not the function you defined, but it is executed.

Comment: try renaming the function `focus`, see if that works

Comment: @FelixKling: Its not executed. And thanks for completely ignoring my post.

Comment: @HBellamy: I tried renaming, shortly after I posted, to focus2 and it seems to work.  Very strange.

Comment: `show` is called *after* `focus`. Do you think the interpreted just skips a statement? And if `focus` would throw an error or not exist, `show` wouldn't be executed. *Edit*: Regarding your last comment, that means that the `focus` function you called was not the one you defined (and that's actually what I meant). Some engines don't let you override certain global properties.

Comment: @FelixKling: Do you think the interpreted just skips a statement? I have no idea, that's the question.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks. Is there a list of these somewhere.  It doesn't work in FF 3.X or IE8.

Comment: I don't know of any. FWIW, it seems to work fine in Chrome. A general solution is to avoid global variables at all and define everything in a new scope: `(function(){ /* your code here */ }());`.

Comment: focus applies only to LABEL, INPUT, SELECT, TEXTAREA and BUTTON.

Comment: @hornetbzz: `window` has a `focus` method too (at least in Chrome) and that is what is causing the trouble here as far as I understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have a renaming issue here.

Just rename the function `focus` to `focusX` or something different, this works for me in my test case.

Remember to update the call to `focus` in the href, to `focusX`

Comment: Will mark as correct when the timer expires.  Any ideas for a new name; emphasize, snap cursor? I can't think of a good one.

Answer (score 4):

It probably *is* calling the "focus" method, but what's happening is that the default action of the `<a>` tag is stealing it back.  Try this:

```
function focus(id)
{
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e != null)
    {
       setTimeout(function() { e.focus(); }, 1);
    }
}
```

By running the call to "focus" in a separate event loop, you can make sure that your element grabs the focus after the handling of the "click" is done.